# SSAS Build in TFS

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, ssas

How do I build an SSAS Cube Project in TFS?
For

1) DatabaseProjects: it is MSBuild

2) SSIS: Devenv.exe with SSIS Project directory

How would I build in Team Foundation Server 2015 for SSAS cube? What is the command line script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Same as SSIS

Use Devenv.exe with SSAS Project directory